# how to filter out items from FileInfo?

Tags: sql, powershell, t-sql

**How do we filter out  items from $filesSorted?**

I am getting a list of files:

```
  $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $SqlFilesDirectory -File -Filter *.sql
  $filesSorted = $files |Sort-Object -Property Name
```

**$filesSorted**

```
20211026_111111.sql 
20211026_222222.sql 
20211026_333333.sql
```

I'm also getting back query results:

`$filesAlreadyApplied = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $DBName -Username $SvcAdminAccount -Password $SvcAdminPassword -Query "SELECT PatchFileName FROM [dbo].[PatchLog]"`

**$filesAlreadyApplied**

```
PatchFileName : 20211026_111111
PatchFileName : 20211026_222222
```

How do we remove items from `$filesSorted` that exist in `$filesAlreadyApplied`?

Comment: `$filesSorted = $filesSorted | Where Name -notin $filesAlreadyApplied.PatchFileName`

Comment: @AdminOfThings Replace `Where Name` with `Where BaseName`, then it should work.